# Deleting rows with LEFT join and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I'm trying to delete records on table based on another table its status.

```
delete from hp_visitors_data
left join hp_programs_list
  on hp_visitors_data.visitor_program_viewed = hp_programs_list.id
where hp_programs_list.program_add_status = 3
group by hp_visitors_data.visitor_program_viewed
```

But I keep getting an error, what I'm doing wrong?

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'left join hp_programs_list
>     on hp_visitors_data.visitor_program_viewed = hp_pro' at line 2

Comment: A left join in a delete is indeed an odd thing

Comment: What is the error that you keep on getting?

Comment: edited, added an error

Comment: remove the group by

Comment: In mysql the use of join in a delete is perfectly legal  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For a delete you should use an inner join so you work only on the rows that match*
anyway  you are using a  group by without aggregation function  but overall you need  a table for delete

```
  delete hp_visitors_data.*  
  from hp_visitors_data
  INNER  join hp_programs_list
    on hp_visitors_data.visitor_program_viewed = hp_programs_list.id 
      and hp_programs_list.program_add_status = 3
```

Comment: seems like working solution, just have to deal with big load of records. adding `order by` would work I guess.

Comment: Order by a delete statements is not sense ..  the delete work indipendtly of the order  of the colums . .. if you need  best performance  .. add  proper index .. .

Comment: @scaisEdge Where is the answer to the OP's "GROUP BY"?

Comment: @datsb   a group by without an aggregation function  have not sense  (eventually can be used  DISTICNT) averall in the code of the OP .. if you have doubts .. try explain these doubs